# vertically align anchor with image inside a div

Tags: css, wordpress

I have tried many many methods for this but I just cant get it. Rather embarrassing after 3 years doing front end work - but I just cant waste any more time on this.

I have a WordPress image gallery, I need to vertically centre the images in it. I have tried setting height, line height and vertical align:middle - but no joy.

The images are added by the user - so the sizes and total number is not static - so solutions that target an individual element height specifically, isn't suitable.

the url:
http://www.europa-international.net/

```
<dl class="gallery-item ">
<dt class="gallery-icon">
    <a href="http://www.europa-international.net/our-videos/snapshot-1-02-01-2014-15-33/" title="Snapshot 1 (02-01-2014 15-33)"><img width="125" height="70" src="http://www.europa-international.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Snapshot-1-02-01-2014-15-33.png" class="attachment-homepage-gallery" alt="Latest Promo Videos"></a>
</dt>
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption">Latest Promo Videos</dd>
```

```
#gallery-1 .gallery-icon {
    height: 104px;
    line-height: 104px;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-icon a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and many variations (giving the anchor height/line-height:104px,display:block, vertical-align:middle) discussed on this site.

edit: posting a fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/DE4ph/2/

also - the duplicate answer solution isn't suitable as I cant (easily) change the markup as its generated by WordPress.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Show us some basic CSS of what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is give the parent container a line-height with the same value as the container itself (i.e. 200px), and then set a vertical-align:middle to the image.

```
.gallery-icon { 
    height: 200px; 
    line-height: 200px; 
}
.gallery-icon img { 
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/B78nD/

Comment: sorry I have tried this. The immediate parent of the image is an anchor. But I have tried your method on the parent of the anchor (you cant give line-height/height to an anchor as its an inline element). I also have tried display:block with line-height/height on the anchor with vertical-align on the image - also, no dice. This is a real twizzler.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle with your actual HTML + CSS?

Answer (score 1):

**One option** out of many is to set the container *div* to position: relative, then add to the *anchor* the following styles:

position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: -62.5px;
  margin-top: -35px;

***Another option is using vertical-align:***

```
#gallery-1 .gallery-icon {
    height: 104px;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-icon a {
     line-height: 104px;
}

#gallery-1 .gallery-icon a img {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

BTW
If the image it's self is inside the div which is inside the anchor - from what I know it's not recommended way to HTML. You can instead change the display of the image to block or inline-block.

Comment: I know where your going with that - but it only really applies to the smallest image, I need them all to be positioned vertically for future iterations of the gallery - thanks though.

Comment: the image isn't inside a div that's inside an anchor - the markup is as in the example. Your right you cant have a div inside an anchor. Also, I have tried changing the image to display:block & inline-block

Comment: Hey, I think I've got it now, check it up...